# Redis with Twemproxy vs memcached

Tags: python, caching, twitter, redis

So referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558465/memcache-vs-redis) question, the top post states that the biggest concern of Redis is its scalability in terms of robust clustering. I was wondering if using Redis with [`Twemproxy`](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy), an open-source proxy developed my Twitter for memcache and redis, would alleviate that problem to the point where my main cache can just be Redis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by robust clustering.

If you need a solution robust enough to support storage (and not caching), or if you consider you cannot afford to loose your cached data, then twemproxy (or any other proxy solution) is not enough. This is true for both Memcached or Redis. For this kind of clustering requirements, you will be better served by things like Couchbase, Infinispan, or even Riak, and Cassandra.

Now if you need a caching solution with automatic sharding, consistent hashing, and proper management of server eviction (or black-listing), then twemproxy works fine with both Redis and Memcached. Performance of twemproxy is excellent.

Comment: It is unadvised to use both? Redis for complex structures and memcached for the actual data caching?

Comment: Well, it is certainly possible to use both at the same time, but usually the performance/scalability advantage of memcached over Redis does not justify the extra complexity. Redis is good enough for most caching purpose.

Comment: Is there a memcached equivalent to lists or would you have to do some string splitting with the key value pair

Comment: There is no equivalent to the list as it is defined in Redis. Now, some list operations (but not all of them) can probably be simulated by using the append/prepend feature of memcached and a serialization format.