# symfony2: Better choice for better memory performance

Tags: symfony, redis, memcached, session-variables

My question is about the fast storage into RAM. Actually my project is a big symfony2 app, and I use a lot session storage (`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session`). I'd like to try something else because I'm not totally happy with symfony2 session since it stores only simple types in it, objects are not allowed. I did a search and redis seems to be the perfect choice BUT someone suggested memcache.

Could memcached be better than redis? Is redis worth a try (despite the learning time we've to spend on it)?

Comment: I would recommend having a read on this article 
     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558465/memcache-vs-redis

Comment: What makes you think you can't store an object in the session?  Examine the session using the toolbar after signing in.  I think you will find a number of objects stored by the security context.