# Redis or memcached - which is best

Tags: spring, microservices

Which cache application is best for spring boot microservice,redis or memcached? I have compared more or less both have same features, please anyone suggest me

Comment: Detailed answer is provide in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558465/memcached-vs-redis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memcached vs. Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558465/memcached-vs-redis)

Comment: They are just doing comparison,I know redis is little bit better than memcached but my question is which is better for specifically spring boot microservices.