# Performence tuning by caching sql results in text files?

Tags: php, sql, performance, caching

I've a php project that manages courses that contains mostly text. It's separated in sections and lections and requires many SQL queries to build the site.

Is it a big performance increase if I cache the SQL queries in text files and load them from there?

The texts won't change for a long time while other small attributes change continuously.

As an example:
Is it faster to read 1000 Chars from a text file than to read 1000 Chars from a SQL-Column?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a QA about caching performance [Session VS File VS Memcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197859/session-vs-file-vs-memcache-for-a-cache-in-php#1197965). Don't forget to look into [Memcache VS Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558465/memcached-vs-redis) as well

Comment: Answer is, it depends

Comment: depends on what?